# Can't insert an element *after* selection in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It looks like d3 has no way to insert an element *after* a selection.

Taking a modified version of the very first tutorial as an example where the data array has a label and a value:

```
data = [ { label: "Ten", value: 10 }, { label: "Fifteen", value: 15 } ];
d3.select(".chart").selectAll("div").data(data)
  .enter()
    .append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return d.value * 10 + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

I can't find any function that would allow me to automatically insert a label with the label text *after* each div.  The closest I can get is the following Code Pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qHIcn

But I don't want it *inside* the selected element, I want it *after*, so it should display the label outside the graph.

**Update**

For anyone who wants an example of the solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ICkeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by generating a hierarchy of elements. The idea is that each `div`/`label` pair would be grouped in a container element (e.g. another `div`), which you can then append the two elements to. The code would look something like this.

```
var divs = d3.select(".chart").selectAll("div").data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div");
divs.append("div")
  .style("width", function(d) { return d.value * 10 + "px"; });
divs.append("label")
  .html(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

You are correct that D3 provides no functions to append elements after a selection (or before a selection for that matter). That's because you are operating *on* selections. That is, selections and data correspond to each other and just as it doesn't make sense to have data outside other data, D3 doesn't really allow to consider elements outside a selection.